# How to slot custom components in React-Ionic?

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, ionic-react

Pardon my absolute ignorance, I’m new to React, but how can I use slots in Ionic React since React has no directives, like Angular? I mean, lets say I’m wanting to add some FontAwesome Icons but since they don’t have the slot attribute, how can I slot them in a `IonButton` “start” slot?

Should I create a custom component for slotting? If so, how is that possible in Ionic?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `<IonIcon>` component with a custom SVG.  As an Ionic component, `<IonIcon>` supports slots just like `<IonButton>`.

According to the [documentation on IonIcon](https://ionic.io/ionicons/usage):

> To use a custom SVG, provide its url in the src attribute to request
> the external SVG file. The src attribute works the same as  in that the url must be accessible from the webpage that's
> making a request for the image. Additionally, the external file can
> only be a valid svg and does not allow scripts or events within the
> svg element.

Font Awesome [has an SVG variant](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/svg-sprites) which you could use with `<IonIcon>` as a custom SVG as described above.